# Issue creating generic wrapper for async library

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous

I have a class Library https://github.com/trydis/FIFA-Ultimate-Team-2014-Toolkit I want to make a wrapper for, instead of just calling FutClient I want to make a FutClientWrapper where I can handle exceptions, reloggin and loggin the interface I want to wrap is https://github.com/trydis/FIFA-Ultimate-Team-2014-Toolkit/blob/master/UltimateTeam.Toolkit/IFutClient.cs

So I made http://pastebin.com/0EJdCbbr

Code snippet

```
    public async Task<AuctionResponse> SearchAsync(SearchParameters searchParameters)
    {
        return await Invoke(f => f.SearchAsync(searchParameters), searchParameters);
    }

    public async Task<AuctionResponse> PlaceBidAsync(AuctionInfo auctionInfo, uint bidAmount = 0)
    {
        return await Invoke(f => f.PlaceBidAsync(auctionInfo, bidAmount), auctionInfo);
    }

    public async Task<Item> GetItemAsync(long resourceId)
    {
        return await Invoke(f => f.GetItemAsync(resourceId), resourceId);
    }

    public TResult Invoke<TResult>(Func<FutClient, TResult> func, object requestDetails = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string exceptionMessage = null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (LastException + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30) < DateTime.Now)
            {
                TResult result = func(_futClient);
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
```

Here I try to wrap and catch any exception thrown inside the Futclient, but instead I get a null exception in for example this line

```
   return await Invoke(f => f.GetItemAsync(resourceId), resourceId);
```

And it seems its because my

```
TResult result = func(_futClient);
                return result;
```

Is not run async and it just returns an empty response (All null values)

So I changed it to look like http://pastebin.com/pJkPr2xN

Code snippet:

```
    public async Task<AuctionResponse> GetTradePileAsync()
    {
        return await NewInvoke<AuctionResponse>(new Task<object>(() => _futClient.GetTradePileAsync()));
    }

    public async Task<WatchlistResponse> GetWatchlistAsync()
    {
        return await NewInvoke<WatchlistResponse>(new Task<object>(() => _futClient.GetWatchlistAsync()));
    }

    public async Task<TResult> NewInvoke<TResult>(Task<object> taskToRun) where TResult : class
    {
        try
        {
            taskToRun.Start();
            Task.WaitAll(taskToRun);
            return taskToRun.Result as TResult;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            //ex.InnerException
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;

        }
    }
```

But also here I get exceptions outside my invoke method

So how should I make this so it handles both Task and Task as a response type and takes x number of arguments

And it should then throw any exceptions inside the Invoke method so I only have one place where exceptions needs to be caught

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `await` inside the try block before you return, otherwise the exception will not be cought by the catch. Your first attempt was actually closer to the correct way to do it.

```
public async Task<TResult> Invoke<TResult>(Func<FutClient, Task<TResult>> func, object requestDetails = null,
    [CallerMemberName] string exceptionMessage = null)
{
    try
    {
        if (LastException + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            TResult result = await func(_futClient).ConfigureAwait(false); //Here we both await for the result and set `ConfigureAwait` to false so we don't need to waist extra time trying to marshal back on to the original Synchronization context as we have no need for it for the rest of the method.
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //...
```

You then just use it like the following

```
public Task<AuctionResponse> PlaceBidAsync(AuctionInfo auctionInfo, uint bidAmount = 0)
{
    return Invoke(f => f.PlaceBidAsync(auctionInfo, bidAmount), auctionInfo);
}
```

There is no need to `await` in this outer function, you can just directly return the Task returned by `Invoke`

Comment: There is no ConfigureAwait on the func, do I need to set something up before I can call that?

Comment: If I do where TResult : Task I get Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'TResult'

Comment: Nwm didnt see you put Task<TResult> in the method signiture, now it cant handle methods with returntype Task though

Comment: @Mech0z Well your old version could not handle methods with return type `Task` either, you just need a 2nd overload with a `Func<FutClient, Task>` and have it return `Task`. Also `ConfigureAwait(` is a method of `Task` and `Task<T>`. The code I did is equivalent to `Task<TResult> task = func(_futClient); TResult result = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);`